# How can i Have a Server side onClick function of a div?

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a div..inside the div i have an image and name..now when i will click on the div the div will have a server side click that means it will have a codebehind function..how to do it?? or how to make my div a button where i don't have to change my div...

my code

```
<div class="tutorial" style="margin-left:5px;">
         TUTORIAL<div class="firstico" style="margin-left:70px;margin-top:-17px;">
         </div>
     </div>
```

how can i have a server side onclick function of this div???

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer. But you can make a button and hide it. Handle the click event of div via Jquery and then on click of div, make the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1090438.aspx

You should implement `IPostBackEventHandler` for your page and register div.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
You can make div `runat="server"`:

*C#*

```
  <div class="tutorial" style="margin-left:5px;"
     runat="server" id="tutorial" onClick="tutorial_Click">

     TUTORIAL<div class="firstico" style="margin-left:70px;margin-top:-17px;">
     </div>
 </div>
```

```
private void tutorial_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
     // do stuff
}
```

*VB.NET*

```
 <div class="tutorial" style="margin-left:5px;"
     runat="server" id="tutorial">

     TUTORIAL<div class="firstico" style="margin-left:70px;margin-top:-17px;">
     </div>
 </div>
```

```
Private Sub tutorial_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) handles tutorial.Click Then
     // do stuff
End Sub
```

**Option 2:**
OR [call `__doPostBack()` via client](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/how-postback-works-in-asp-net/) (Javascript)

```
 <div class="tutorial" style="margin-left:5px;"
      onclick="__doPostBack('tutorial', 'click');">

     TUTORIAL<div class="firstico" style="margin-left:70px;margin-top:-17px;">
     </div>
 </div>
```

```
private void PageLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
     // sttufs
     [...]

     // my stuff for tutorial click
     if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "tutorial" && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "click"){
         TutorialClicked();
     }
}

private void TutorialClicked(){
     // do stuff
}
```